# Is it cheaper to mail a small package to Germany from Turkey, Bulgaria, or Romania?

Tags: turkey, romania, bulgaria, mail

I'm travelling from Turkey slowly to Romania via Bulgaria and I have a package that must be sent to Germany. The item will be like a slightly larger tube of toothpaste in size, shape and weight. It is not highly valuable.

Which of the three countries has the cheapest rates for a small package and is there a trade-off with reliability?

Comment: @Matthew: Feel free to start a meta discussion about this if you feel strongly that it should be re-opened.  "We didn't discuss it on meta" in itself is not enough reason to re-open.  Additionally, this is the sort of conversation that belongs on meta -- here in the comments it serves only as noise.  I'll be cleaning up the comments in a bit to remove this exchange.

Comment: @matthew An explanation was given in the close message. If you find that insufficient, meta is the place to handle it so that *everyone* can participate. It isn't fair to establish precedent for on- or off- topicness of a subject in the comments of a closed question where most users will never see it or have the chance to weigh in.  Regardless of your *intent*, that is the *effect* of having this sort of discussion in comments.  That is why we insist that it happen in meta only.

Comment: Meta post: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/99/13

Comment: This question was closed because it's about shipping, not travelling...

Comment: It's about shipping and travelling. A question of shipping while not travelling would not have looked like this and I wouldn't have asked it here.

Comment: If the poster asked about romantic restaurants in Rome, would it be closed because it is about eating, not travelling?  Shipping items home is a common situation travelers encounter, so I'd consider this question on-topic.

Comment: -1 I very much doubt anybody knows from the top of their head the price of sending a packet to Germany from those three countries, plus the exchange rates between their currencies to allow comparing the prices, so this question is asking: "please look it up and do the math so I don't have to." Plus it's highly unlikely to ever be useful to anybody else. I would leave closed.

Comment: @fkraiem Agreed. Are we going to have a question for every size of parcel, every subset of possible countries you could send it from and every destination country?

Comment: No, we are not going to have. Are we going to have too many rhetorical questions in comments?

Comment: @pnuts No, we're not. Because we'd reject those questions as too broad. If this question is travel, it's too broad; if it's not travel, it's off-topic. Either way, it should stay closed.